# kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING on windows

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to start apache server on my windows machine. But while doing so i get this error `kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING` and the process stops. Note that i have zookeeper process started before running this and it started fine.

console log for zookeeper below:-

```
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,818] INFO Server environment:java.library.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;"C:\Users\Ripesh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin";;. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,826] INFO Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Ripesh\AppData\Local\Temp\ 
    (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,826] INFO Server environment:java.compiler=<NA> 
    (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,834] INFO Server environment:os.name=Windows 10 
    (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,834] INFO Server environment:os.arch=amd64 
    (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,842] INFO Server environment:os.version=10.0 
    (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,850] INFO Server environment:user.name=Ripesh 
    (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,850] INFO Server environment:user.home=C:\Users\Ripesh 
    (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,858] INFO Server environment:user.dir=C:\kafka2.7 
    (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,858] INFO Server environment:os.memory.free=497MB 
    (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,858] INFO Server environment:os.memory.max=512MB 
    (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,866] INFO Server environment:os.memory.total=512MB 
    (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,882] INFO minSessionTimeout set to 6000 
    (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,882] INFO maxSessionTimeout set to 60000 
    (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,898] INFO Created server with tickTime 3000 minSessionTimeout 6000 
    maxSessionTimeout 60000 datadir C:\kafka2.7\zookeeper\version-2 snapdir C:\kafka2.7\zookeeper\version-2 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,938] INFO Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory as server connection factory (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,946] INFO Configuring NIO connection handler with 10s sessionless connection timeout, 1 selector thread(s), 8 worker threads, and 64 kB direct buffers. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,946] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,972] INFO zookeeper.snapshotSizeFactor = 0.33 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,979] INFO Snapshotting: 0x0 to C:\kafka2.7\zookeeper\version-2\snapshot.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog)   
    [2021-02-20 16:24:30,984] INFO Snapshotting: 0x0 to C:\kafka2.7\zookeeper\version-2\snapshot.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog)
    [2021-02-20 16:24:31,008] INFO Using checkIntervalMs=60000 maxPerMinute=10000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ContainerManager)
   [2021-02-20 16:29:39,625] INFO Creating new log file: log.1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog)
[2021-02-20 16:29:58,708] INFO Expiring session 0x100011044520000, timeout of 18000ms exceeded (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-02-20 16:48:34,467] INFO Expiring session 0x100011044520001, timeout of 18000ms exceeded (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-02-20 16:48:34,471] INFO Expiring session 0x100011044520002, timeout of 18000ms exceeded (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
```

Error log in console when kafka server started:-

```
        [2021-02-21 06:30:58,108] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:52365, server: localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
    [2021-02-21 06:31:16,104] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
    [2021-02-21 06:31:16,108] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 18001ms for sessionid 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
    [2021-02-21 06:31:16,114] INFO Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 18001ms for sessionid 0x0, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
    [2021-02-21 06:31:16,340] INFO Session: 0x0 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
    [2021-02-21 06:31:16,342] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
    [2021-02-21 06:31:16,357] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
    [2021-02-21 06:31:16,372] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
    kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
            at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:262)
            at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:119)
            at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1881)
            at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:441)
            at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:466)
            at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:233)
            at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
            at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
            at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
    [2021-02-21 06:31:16,379] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
    [2021-02-21 06:31:16,391] INFO App info kafka.server for 1 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
    [2021-02-21 06:31:16,393] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
    [2021-02-21 06:31:16,394] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
    [2021-02-21 06:31:16,397] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
    PS C:\kafka2.7>
```

It looks from log there is a 18000msec timeout defined.Strangely after a few mins when i started kafka server process again i was able to start it without any issues. Note i started zookeeper from zookeper-server-start.bat provided in kafka package rather than apache zookeeper package.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/

Comment: Both of those logs are from Zookeeper, not Kafka, and there are only info messages

Comment: @OneCricketeer updated the question with Kafka server start log.